# How can we use count() with conditional sql in select() of laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, join, count

I have two tables as shown below. I am using Laravel DB method to join this table. But I am not getting how can I get the count of marks of students as per failed or passed. `0-failed` `1-passed`.

Expected result:

```
1. Student Name
2. Student Id,
3. Count of failed based on student Id as count_failed
4. Total Marks based on student Id as total_marks
```

table `students`

```
`+----+-----------+
 | id |   name    |
 +----+-----------+
 |  1 | John Doe  |
 |  2 | Mark P    |
 |  3 | Pen Henry |
 +----+-----------+`
```

table `students_marks`:

```
 +----+------------+-------+-----------+
 | id | student_id | marks |is_failed  |
 +----+------------+-------+-----------+
 |  1 |          1 |    55 |  0        |
 |  2 |          2 |    44 |  1        |
 |  3 |          1 |    11 |  1        |
 |  4 |          2 |    10 |  0        |
 |  5 |          2 |    11 |  1        |
 |  6 |          2 |    20 |  0        |
 +----+------------+-------+-----------+
```

Below is query which I used:

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('contacts', 'students.id', '=', 'students_marks.user_id')
        ->select('student.*')
        ->get();
```

I am unable to get how can we use `count()` with conditional SQL in `select()` of laravel?

Comment: so you want to count of pass and fail marks?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
$users = DB::table('students s')
    ->leftJoin('students_mark sm', 's.id', '=', 'sm.user_id')
    ->groupBy('sm.id')
    ->select(DB::raw('s.id, s.name, SUM(sm.is_failed) AS num_failed, COUNT(sm.user_id) AS total_cnt'))
    ->get();
```

This corresponds to the following raw MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.name,
    SUM(sm.is_failed) AS num_failed,
    COUNT(sm.user_id) AS total_cnt
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN students_marks sm
    ON s.id = sm.user_id
GROUP BY
    s.id;
```

Note: It is acceptable in ANSI SQL to select the `name` field in the above `GROUP BY` query assuming that `student#id` is the primary key column for that table.  If the above query gives an `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` error, then simply add `s.name` to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I have 20 odd fields and I need to add this 20 odd fields into  `groupBy()` else its giving me error of `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY `.@ Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Also here we are unable to get failed count @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Then just make sure that every additional field beyond `id` which you add to the `SELECT` clause also appears in the `GROUP BY` clause.  In any case, I have answered your original question.

Comment: I think we are missing the logic of count of ` SUM(sm.is_failed) AS num_failed` will sum but we need count

Comment: No, you don't, because `is_failed` is 1 when a failure occurred and zero otherwise, so taking the sum of this field per student gives the number of failures.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $users = DB::table('users')
                ->join('contacts', 'students.id', '=', 'students_marks.user_id')
                 ->select('student.*', DB::raw("count(students_marks.is_failed) as count")))
                 ->where('status', '=', 0)
                 ->get();
```

Try this.
If this is not clear or doesn't work refer [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet

```
$table = DB::table('students_marks');
$table = $table->select(
        \DB::raw('SUM(if(is_failed = '0', 1, 0)) AS failed'), 
        \DB::raw('SUM(if(is_failed = '1', 1, 0)) AS passed'),
        \DB::raw('SUM(marks) AS total'));
        $table = $table->Join('students', 'students.id', '=', 'students_marks.student_id'); 
        $table = $table->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$users = DB::table('students s')
    ->leftJoin('students_mark sm', 's.id', '=', 'sm.student_id')
    ->groupBy('s.id','s.name')
    ->selectRaw("s.id,s.name,SUM(sm.is_failed) AS count_failed,SUM(sm.marks) as total_marks")
    ->get();`